# UIImageView in UIView and not to display image parts out of bounds

Tags: objective-c, iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

How can I solve the problem I mentioned in the title?
So I have an UIImageView and in it there is an UIImage.
My UIImageView is in a View. When I set the origin of the imageview to (-120, -30) then I don't want to see the start of my imageview. Is this possible? Can this be done? How?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the `clipsToBounds` property on the image view to YES.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it tomorrow morning

Comment: I set the clipsToBounds property on my view not on the image view, but anyway it was a good answer. Thanks again!