# How display progressively an UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, uiimageview

I find a way to display progressively an `UIImageView` like that :
[image] 
-> [image]

I don't necessarily want to animate it, but I can't find a way to display only a part of an `UIImageView` by only play with its `frame` or `contentMode` property.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've found my response :

[UIImageView in UIView and not to display image parts out of bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281939/uiimageview-in-uiview-and-not-to-display-image-parts-out-of-bounds)

Answer (score 1):

Put a UIView over the imageview and change the uiview frame accordingly.

Comment: In my context I can't do that because I play with some png.